# Displaying data present in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

need a little help. I am working on SQL server and I need to display data that is in multiple columns but different rows. I tried using a exists but that did not work. And join does not work in this scenario and neither does and/or statement.

```
Part name      supplier01     supplier02     supplier03
a1                 1              3            zzz 
b1                 2              4
c1                 3             zzz
d1                 4                            1
e1                zzz             1             2
```

Now in the example above, part a is sold by supplier 1, 3 and 5. Part b is sold by supplier 2 and 4 so on and so forth.

What I need to do is display a list of all the parts sold by supplier one but in different columns. So the display should look like

```
Part name      supplier01     supplier02     supplier03
a1                 1                                    
d1                                               1
e1                                 1
```

Any help or thoughts are appreciated.
**Update:
Sorry in my initial question I forgot to mention that Partname, supplier01, supplier02, supplier 03 columns are navchar.**

Comment: Look up [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). What will you do if you need supplier #4? Best is to make a linking table `PartSupplier`, then this query is trivial

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select
  part_name,
  case when supplier01 = 'ONEILE' then 'ONEILE' end as supplier01,
  case when supplier02 = 'ONEILE' then 'ONEILE' end as supplier02,
  case when supplier03 = 'ONEILE' then 'ONEILE' end as supplier03
from t
where supplier01 = 'ONEILE' 
   or supplier02 = 'ONEILE' 
   or supplier03 = 'ONEILE'
```

If you want to provide the parameter ('ONEILE') just once, you can do:

```
with p (s) as (select 'ONEILE'::varchar) -- parameter supplier # here
select
  t.part_name,
  case when t.supplier01 = p.s then p.s end as supplier01,
  case when t.supplier02 = p.s then p.s end as supplier02,
  case when t.supplier03 = p.s then p.s end as supplier03
from t
cross join p
where t.supplier01 = p.s or t.supplier02 = p.s or t.supplier03 = p.s
```

Comment: i forgot to mention in my initial inquiry that partname and supplier codes are varchar. Your solution works, thanks a lot for that but i get this error after a quick glimpse of the table: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ONEILE' to data type int.
"

Comment: There is a supplier with the name 'ONEILE' in the supplier01 column

Comment: @Leo You can use a `VARCHAR` as well. See modified answer.

Comment: Thanks Impaler, the issue I ran into is when I use '1' as a parameter it gave me the conversion failed error when I executed the script.

Comment: @Leo Append `::varchar` to the parameter to force its type.

Comment: @Impaler, thank you sooo much. that worked. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if changing the format of the result set would actually be more helpful:

```
select t.partname, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (supplier01, 1), (supplier02, 2), (supplier03, 3)) v(supplier, which)
where supplier = 1;
```

This returns the values in separate rows, with the "column" as a number.  This seems like a more helpful way to represent the information.